# Open view when tapping the text field without opening the keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, swift4

I am developing an app in which I want to open a view when the user clicks on a text field but I don't want to open the keyboard. How can I achieve this?

Comment: create a fake textfield or extend the textfield

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily achieve it by setting an empty [custom input view](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html) to the `textField`:

```
textField.inputView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
```

Then the `textField` can become first responder normally, but this view (with `zero` frame) will be presented instead of the keyboard.

Comment: where I have to write this code. Which delegate should I have to call?

Comment: @V_rohit no need for a delegate, just set it anywhere where you configure the textField (that one line is all you need, call it once at the beginning when you configure the textfield)

Comment: Okay Its working

Answer (score 3):

Set your ViewController as your TextFields delegate using

```
self.yourTextfield.delegate = self
```

and now implement the UITextFieldDelegate as shown below

```
extension ViewController : UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool   {
        //Load your VC here
        return false
    }
}
```

Thats all :) Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You can use below `textField Delegate` Method

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        yourTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        //code for show view
    }
```

Hope it will help!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a **tap gesture recognizer** to the text field.

```
let tapGestRec = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(textFieldTapped))
textField.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestRec)
```